# Efficient comparison of 100.000 vectors

Tags: java, database, visual-studio, math, vector

I save 100.000 Vectors of in a database. Each vector has a dimension 60. (int vector[60])

Then I take one and want present vectors to the user in order of decreasing similarity to the chosen one.

I use [Tanimoto Classifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) to compare 2 vectors:

[image]

Is there any methods to avoid doing through all entries in the database?

One more thing! I don't need to sort all vectors in the database. I whant to get top 20 the most similar vectors. So maybe we can roughly threshold 60% of entries and use the rest for sorting. What do you think?

Comment: You will have to go through all your entries at least once in order to determine its coefficient between that vector and your chosen vector.

Comment: 60 dimensions, or a magnitude of 60?

Comment: Regardless of the final method you chose for partitioning/searching,  you should store your database with the vectors NORMALIZED to unit magnitude. That makes any eventual comparison a simple dot product, eliminating two magnitude computes and a divide.

Comment: He can do the dot product anyway, the numbers will be bigger, but they'll sort just as well.

Comment: Waiting for lerax to tell us what he meant by "length" feels like waiting for Godot.

Comment: Lenght is a dimension of vectors.

Comment: The length of a Vetor is defined as the square-root of the summ of the square of the components or: Assuming v is a vector with n components v1 to vn, then the length of v is: |v| = sqrt(v1^2 + ... + vn^2)

Comment: @Kevin D. You should use the word "magnitude" for that. We've already had one "length" mixup on this question. :-)

Comment: A lot depedends on what kind of data is in those vectors. There is a possibility to make some good optimizations based on that. If you can, answer these questions: 1) Do values in those vectors have a range, or can they be any double value? Can values be negative? Do all elements in vectors have the same range, or some are binary, some real in range [0..1], some in range [-1..1], some integers in [1..100], etc? Can you normalize vectors and still get good enough similarity? Are those 100000 vectors distributed more or less evenly, or are they clustered?

Comment: I assume you're allowing the database to be preprocessed? Otherwise you'd have to stream through every value no matter what.

Comment: Note that 2^60 is a __whole__ lot bigger than 100.000. This vector space is quite flat; I wouldn't expect more than 2log(100000) = 17 dimensions.

Comment: Are these vectors binary?  That is 0,1 are the only values?

Comment: Notice that you can pre-calculate |A|^2 and |B|^2 so you're basically left with calculating A dot B for each comparison.

@Arno Setagaya: You don't have to do any magnitude computes at all because |A|^2 is A dot A.

Comment: I cannot do this! See my answer below.

Answer (score 24):

First, preprocess your vector list to make each vector normalized.. unit magnitude.
Notice now that your comparison function T() now has magnitude terms that become constant, and the formula can be simplified to finding the largest dot product between your test vector and the values in the database.

Now, think of a new function D = the distance between two points in 60D space. This is classic [L2 distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance), take the difference of each component, square each, add all the squares, and take the square root of the sum.  D(A, B) = sqrt( (A-B)^2)  where A and B are each 60 dimensional vectors.

This can be expanded, though, to  D(A, B) = sqrt(A * A -2*dot(A,B) + B * B).
A and B are unit magnitude, then. And the function D is monotonic, so it won't change the sort order if we remove the sqrt() and look at squared distances. This leaves us with only -2 * dot(A,B).  Thus, miniumizing distance is exactly equivalent to maximizing dot product.

So the original T() classificiation metric can be simplified into finding the highest dot product between the nornalized vectors. And that comparison is shown equivalent to finding the **closest** points to the sample point in 60-D space.

So now all you need to do is solve the equivalent problem of "given a normalized point in 60D space, list the 20 points in the database of normalized sample vectors which are nearest to it."

That problem is a well understood one.. it's [K Nearest Neighbors.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbor_algorithm) 
There are many algorithms for solving this. The most common is classic [KD trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd-tree)
.

But there's a problem. KD trees have an O(e^D) behavior.. high dimensionality quickly becomes painful. And 60 dimensions is definitely in that extremely painful category. Don't even try it.

There are several alternative general techniques for high D nearest neighbor however.
[This paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.62.542) gives a clear method.

But in practice, there's a great solution involving yet another transform. If you have a metric space (which you do, or you wouldn't be using the Tanimoto comparison), you can reduce the dimensionality of the problem by a 60 dimensional rotation. That sounds complex and scary, but it's very common.. it's a form of singular value decomposition, or eigenvalue decomposition.  In statistics, it's known as [Principal Components Analysis.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_components_analysis)

Basically this uses a simple linear computation to find what directions your database really spans. You can collapse the 60 dimensions down to a lower number, perhaps as low as 3 or 4, and still be able to accurately determine nearest neighbors.
There are tons of software libraries for doing this in any language, see [here](http://astro.u-strasbg.fr/~fmurtagh/mda-sw/) for example.

Finally, you'll do a classic K nearest neighbors in probably only 3-10 dimensions.. you can experiment for the best behavior. There's a terrific library for doing this called [Ranger](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/implement/ranger/implement.shtml), but you can use other libraries as well.  A great side benefit is you don't even need to store all 60 components of your sample data any more!

The nagging question is whether your data really can be collapsed to lower dimensions without affecting the accuracy of the results. In practice, the PCA decomposition can tell you the maximum residual error for whatever D limit you choose, so you can be assured it works. Since the comparison points are based on a distance metric, it's very likely they are intensely correlated, unlike say hash table values.

So the summary of the above:

1. Normalize your vectors, transforming your problem into a K-nearest neighbor problem in 60 dimensions
2. Use Principal Components Analysis to reduce dimensionality down to a manageable limit of say 5 dimensions
3. Use a K Nearest Neighbor algorithm such as Ranger's KD tree library to find nearby samples.

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled by your statement, why do you think 60 dimensions is a lot? High dimensional spaces are spaces with millions of dimensions, and in my experience anything short of a thousand or so dimensions can be dealt with simply using just brute-force (even in the order of 100,000 vectors). Dimensionality reductions like SVD or PCA are usually used to bring millions of dimensions down to a few tens of thousands, but how much information can there be left in a 3 dimensional vector? just my two cents.

Comment: @sds: Brute force of course works, but the submitter specifically says he wants to find a method that is not brute-force.

60D a lot for the KD partitioning... you get inefficient sorting in high dimensions because each cut can only reduce the average radius by 2^(1/D). By reducing the dimensionality, you'll get a KD tree that could find the 20 closest points in roughly 30 steps. (the algorithm is now nicely O(log(N)) for lookup cost, so adding more points is cheap). How many dimensions you can reduce to is data dependent, but 3-5 is typical, and the PCA fit will tell you the residual error.

Comment: @Arno Setagaya: That's a fair point I guess. It still sounds like you'll be throwing away a whole lot of useful information to shave off a second or so of computation, but like you said, that was the question. I'd be interested to hear what the OP ended up trying, and what gains it bought him.

Comment: It is my impression, that the method you are proposing would give approximate results, i.e. the top 20 vectors after normalization, reducing dimensionality sometimes will differ from the top 20 found by using Tanimoto Classifier on original vectors. Author hasn't yet stated if it is ok for his problem, so maybe you should make this point clearer in your answer. Anyway, your suggestion seems well thought out and nicely explained.

Comment: @Juozas, no, you can find the top 20 completely accurate. The dimensional reduction tells you the maximum residual error of the truncated dimensiona, and you can use that as an extra required radius when searching the KD to guarantee you find all points that have any possibility of influencing your best candidate ranking.

Comment: you just gave a summary worth 30 hours of lectures. quite dense.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:**

After you made clear that `60` is the dimension of your space, not the length of the vectors, the answer below is not applicable for you, so I'll keep it just for history.

---

Since your vectors are normalized, you can employ `kd-tree` to find the neighbors within an `MBH` of incremental hypervolume.

No database I'm aware of has native support of `kd-tree`, so you can try to implement the following solution in `MySQL`, if you are searching for a limited number of closest entries:

- Store the projections of the vectors to each of `2`-dimensional space possible (takes `n * (n - 1) / 2` columns)
- Index each of these columns with a `SPATIAL` index
- Pick a square `MBR` of a given area within any projection. The product of these `MBR`'s will give you a hypercube of a limited hypervolume, which will hold all vectors with a distance not greater than a given one.
- Find all projections within all `MBR`'s using `MBRContains`

You'll still need to sort within this limited range of values.

For instance, you have a set of `4`-dimensional vectors with magnitude of `2`:

```
(2, 0, 0, 0)
(1, 1, 1, 1)
(0, 2, 0, 0)
(-2, 0, 0, 0)
```

You'll have to store them as follows:

```
p12  p13  p14  p23  p24  p34
---  ---  ---  ---  ---  ---
2,0  2,0  2,0  0,0  0,0  0,0
1,1  1,1  1,1  1,1  1,1  1,1
0,2  0,0  0,0  2,0  2,0  0,0
-2,0 -2,0 -2,0 0,0  0,0  0,0
```

Say, you want similarity with the first vector `(2, 0, 0, 0)` greater than `0`.

This means having the vectors inside the hypercube: `(0, -2, -2, -2):(4, 2, 2, 2)`.

You issue the following query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    vectors
WHERE   MBRContains('LineFromText(0 -2, 4 2)', p12)
        AND MBRContains('LineFromText(0 -2, 4 2)', p13)
        …
```

, etc, for all six columns

Comment: Even knowing neighbors, won't he still have to find all the similarities? I suppose there's a possible gain in grouping for sort routines which do better when the array starts with a significant degree of sortedness.

Comment: @Nosredna: If his vectors are normalized (they all are of length 60), then having neighbors inside a hypercube with edge less that 60 means having neighbors with a certain similarity greater than 0. The less is the edge, the greater is the similarity.

Comment: The naive approach is O(n) (or O(n^2) for all possible selections of the preferred vector) in space and time. Is this actually faster or more compact?

Comment: @dmckee: If he needs all values then he should just count and sort. If he need TOP N values or values within given threshold of similarity, then the indexes will be faster.

Answer (score 2):

So the following information can be cached:

- Norm of the chosen vector
- The dot product A.B, reusing it for both the numerator and the denominator in a given T(A,B) calculation.

If you only need the N closest vectors or if you are doing this same sorting process multiple times, there may be further tricks available.  (Observations like T(A,B)=T(B,A), caching the vector norms for all the vectors, and perhaps some sort of thresholding/spatial sort).

Comment: Whoit do you meen by "T(A,B) = T(B,A) cutting down the number of comparisons by half" ? I just take one vector and compare it with others. I dont need to compare vectors with each other.

Comment: I apologize.  I misread and thought you were performing this calculation for multiple vectors as you would in clustering algorithms.  You can at least still cache the norm of your chosen vector and reuse the dot product in numerator/denominator.

Answer (score 2):

In order to sort something, you need a sorting key for each item.    So you *will* need to process each entry at least once to calculate the key.

Is that what you think of?

=======
Moved comment here:

Given the description you cannot avoid looking at all entries to calculate your similarity factor. If you tell the database to use the similarity factor in the "order by" clause you can let it do all the hard work. Are you familiar with SQL?

Comment: Right! But maybe I can threshold 50% of entries at the start of computation?

Comment: How do you know what to cut out if you don't process everything?

Answer (score 1):

In short, no, probably not any way to avoid going through all the entries in the database.  One qualifier on that; if you have a significant number of repeated vectors, you may be able to avoid reprocessing exact repeats.

Comment: Sorting the vectors ahead of time would make it easier to determine if the vector has been seen before.

Answer (score 1):

**Newer answer**

How much preprocessing can you do? Can you build "neighborhoods" ahead of time and note which neighborhood each vector is in inside the database? That might let you eliminate many vectors from consideration.

---

**Old answer below, which assumed 60 was magnitude of all the vectors, not the dimension.**

Since the vectors are all the same length (60), I think you're doing too much math. Can't you just do the dot product of the chosen one against each candidate?

In 3D: [image]

Three multiplies. In 2D it's just two multiplies.

Or does that violate your idea of similarity? To me, the most similar vectors are the ones with the least angular distance between them.

Comment: There is an ambiguity in the term "length", he may (or may not) mean 60 dimensional vectors of unknown magnitude. Or you might have it right and he means vectors of magnitude 60, in which case the simplification of the per-comparison math you suggest applies, but he still have to do 99,999 comparisons at a minimum.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean I was assuming he meant magnitude.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to live with approximations, there are a few ways you can avoid having to go through the whole database at runtime. In a background job you can start pre-computing pairwise distances between vectors. Doing this for the whole database is a huge computation, but it does not need to be finished for it to be useful (i.e. start computing distances to 100 random vectors for each vector or so. store results in a database).

Then triangulate. if the distance d between your target vector v and some vector v' is large, then the distance between v and all other v'' that are close to v' will be large(-ish) too, so there is no need to compare them anymore (you will have to find acceptable definitions of "large" yourself though). You can experiment with repeating the process for the discarded vectors v'' too, and test how much runtime computation you can avoid before the accuracy starts to drop. (make a test set of "correct" results for comparisons)

good luck.

sds

Comment: Thank you! But unfurtunatly it doesn't work. The vectors in DB are not sorted anyway? We cannot say that two adjacent vector in DB are similar.

Comment: Why would they need to be sorted? You still need to make a whole bunch of comparisons, it's just that with this approach you can determine entire "regions" in your database that do not need to be checked because they are guaranteed not to contain similar vectors. It's all about removing as much unnecessary computation as possible, but you will still need to do some.

Answer (score 0):

Uh, no?

You only have to do all 99,999 against the one you picked (rather than all `n(n-1)/2` possible pairs), of course, but that's as low as it goes.

---

Looking at your response to [nsanders's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997106/efficient-comparison-of-100000-vectors/997120#997120), it is clear you are already on top of this part. But I've thought of a special case where computing the full set of comparisons might be a win. If:

- the list comes in slowly (say your getting them from some data acquisition system at a fixed, low rate)
- you don't know until the end which one you want to compare to
- you have plenty of storage
- you need the answer fast when you do pick one (and the naive approach isn't fast enough)
- Looks are faster than computing

then you could pre-compute the as the data comes in and just lookup the results per pair at sort time. This might also be effective if you will end up doing many sorts...

Comment: The "real" solution is that you *have* to compare them all. Even having a faster pre-comparer doesn't get you out of that requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Without going trough all entries? It seems not possible.
The only thing you can do is to do the math at insert time (remembering that  [equivalence http://tex.nigma.be/T%2528A%252CB%2529%253DT%2528B%252CA%2529.png](http://tex.nigma.be/T%2528A%252CB%2529%253DT%2528B%252CA%2529.png)  :P ).

This avoids your query to check the list against all the other lists at execution time (but it could heavily increase the space needed for the db)

Answer (score 0):

Another take on this is the all pair problem with a given threshold for some similarity function.
Have a look at bayardo's paper and code here http://code.google.com/p/google-all-pairs-similarity-search/

I do not know if your similarity function matches the approach, but if so, that is another tack to look at. It would also require normalized and sorted vectors in any case.